# Rolling back to previous version in Fluent Migrator

Tags: c#, .net, migration, fluent-migrator

I am attempting to get migrations working with my project using fluent migrator. But due to the lack of documentation I am struggling to figure out how to rollback and have the `Down` method called for my migration class.

I set up the db with an initial version 1 class:

```
[Migration(1)]
public class Baseline : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Execute.Script("1_Baseline\\baseline.sql");
    }

    public override void Down() { }
}
```

I am running migrations via a batch file containing the following:

> "....\tools\fluentmigrator\migrate.exe" --connection "Data
>   Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ekmDomains;Integrated
>   Security=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;" --db SqlServer2005
>   --target "bin\Release\EkmDomains.Migrations.dll"

This works fine. So I then wrote a second migration class just to test it out:

```
[Migration(2)]
public class AddNewTable : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("NewTable").WithColumn("name").AsString();
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Delete.Table("NewTable");
    }
}
```

Again after running the batch file, everything works ok. I then looked at the command line options for the fluent migrator tool, and saw a `--version` option. I assumed that to rollback to a previous version I would simply supply `--version 1` and the `Down` of `AddNewTable` would be called. That, however, did not happent. The console simply displays a 'committing transaction` method then closes. But the table has not been deleted and the version number hasn't changed.

Am I doing this the wrong way or can anyone see some fundamental flaw in how I am doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To migrate down, you use `-t migrate:down`.  Besides down and up, the help for migrate.exe also lists rollback, `rollback:toversion` and `rollback:all`.

Comment: This is all covered in more detail on the [fluent migrator console docs](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/runners/runner-console.html#--task--tvalue-optional)